# Input.GetKeyDown doesn't work when I call it twice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to let a cube drop in unity when i call `Input.GetKeyDown("space")`, and when a cube is dropped, the second cube is generated and drop again when the space is pressed, however, when I press it again it doesn't work, here is my code

```
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        if (!ss)
        {
            shabi.useGravity = true;
            shabi.AddForce(0, 0, -100);
            ss = true;
        }
    }

    if (cube1.transform.position.y == y)
    {
        if (!singleExecution)
        {
            Rigidbody newCube = spawn();
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) //THE PART THAT DOESN'T WORK
            {
                Debug.Log("sb");
                newCube.useGravity = true;
                newCube.AddForce(0, 0, -100);
            }
            y++;
            //cubeY += 2;
            singleExecution = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The function `spawn()` is used for generate another cube, and the second `Input.GetKeyDown` doesn't work, thank you for answering my question

Comment: What did debugging the code show? If there’s gravity and floats I’m assuming the comparison never is true

Comment: Hi there, thank you for answering my question! It didn't show the sb, and I set the gravity of new cube into false in the spawn()

Comment: where are you setting singleExecution to false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem actually already lies in the line before:

```c#
if(cube1.transform.position.y == y)
```

Since your first object uses gravity, what are the odds that the position in one frame matches exactly `y`? Additionally comparing two `float` values might never match even if the value should be the same, see [`Math.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) for more information on that.

This will almost never be true so your code doesn't even reach the `Input` part.

Now you could ofcourse use

```c#
if(Math.Approximately(cube1.transform.position.y, y)
```

trying to still match an exact `y` value but the odds that this matches on a free falling object are still very small!

Instead you should use a qualitative comparison like `<=`. You can either use a wider approximation using the difference between the two values (in this example it matches while the object is less then `+-10cm` appart from the expected `y`):

```c#
if(cube1.transform.position.y - y <= 0.1f)
```

but for fast moving objects (which is usually the case for free falling ones) it might be better to simply check if it is smaller than the desired height:

```c#
if(cube1.transform.position.y <= y)
```

This depends obviously on what exactly your purpose is here.